# por qué a la hora de imprimir en consola en Eclipse utilizando el \n no me imprime lo escrito antes de \n?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Eclipse que utiliza el comando \n para saltar línea y que salgan diferentes opciones, en teoría tendría que imprimir también lo escrito antes de ese comando ya que está dentro de las "" pero no lo imprime. 
El código utilizado es:

```
Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Escoge una opción: \n1: Cuadrado, \n2: Triángulo, \n3: Círculo");
```

El caso es que me salen las opciones de Cuadrado, Triángulo, Círculo, pero no imprime "Escoge una opción" antes de las opciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola compile tu código en mi Eclipse y mostró todas las líneas de código.

Alguna vez me paso algo parecido y era que el resultado estaba quedando en la parte de arriba de la consola. Intenta subir con la barra de desplazamiento tal vez sea eso.

Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Era eso, estaba quedando oculto en la parte de arriba. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Jane_Moonbreaker Bienvenida a SOe. Si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema, por favor márcala como aceptada, tal como se explica en el [tour].